# audit a course vs. take a course for credit

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I have a problem to understand the following sentence:

> It usually costs as much to audit a course as to take it for credit.

In general, I have understood that auditing a course has not any cost. But in the above sentence, it says auditing a course costs as much as taking a course for credit. Maybe I have some problem in understanding the meaning of "audit" and "credit" words. If so, please one clarify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some institutions charge full tuition for a course even if a student is auditing that class instead of taking it for credit.

This makes sense if you think about it. The auditing student is still taking up one of the seats in the classroom, and may be asking questions – therefore using the professor’s time.